# Deny third party iframe page loading

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have a php-page, that should be loaded through iframe on my site.

```
<iframe src="http://domain.com/page.php"></iframe>
```

How can I determine, what site is trying to load this page through iframe and deny page loading if it's loaded not from my domain.com? I need it done as PHP method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`X-Frame-Options` HTTP response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```